# How to view my Windows Live Mesh files on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, shared-folders, windows-live-mesh, onedrive

I use Windows Live Mesh to sync folders.  I've also synced the folders to SkyDrive synced storage.

I'd like to access the files from my iPhone.  So I downloaded the SkyDrive app from Microsoft, but for reasons unknown it does not show files from SkyDrive synced storage.

My question is this: has anyone found a way to view Windows Live Mesh files on the iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [iSMEStorage App](http://smestorage.com/?p=static&page=iphone) to do this. This is how I access my sync'd folders, but they are read only, as this is how Microsoft makes these folders and files available in SkyDrive (even on the web).

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's Live Mesh storage to SkyDrive synced storage is not the same as what's stored in your SkyDrive folders.  See: http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/reviews/2010/06/windows-live-sync-is-frustratingly-bad-it-could-be-awesome.ars

I bridge the two using a mapped network drive (see: http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57347395-285/how-to-map-your-skydrive-folder-in-windows-7/) and a nightly robocopy script that copies the contents of my Mesh folders to the SkyDrive documents folder.  Then my Mesh files are visible in the iPhone SkyDrive app.